# Show that $e^{-t}\int_{0}^{t}\frac{e^{x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx$ is strictly decreasing for $t\geq1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

I want to prove that $e^{-t}\int_{0}^{t}\frac{e^{x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx$ is decreasing
on $[1,\infty[$.

First of all numerical experiments verify this.

I am trying the first derivative test, but stuck with showing that
the sign of the derivative is negative, which is equivalent to showing that 
$$\int_{0}^{t}\frac{e^{x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx> \frac{e^{t}}{\sqrt{t}},\qquad t\geq 1$$.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think I solved it.

Let $f(t):=e^{-t}\int_{0}^{t}\frac{e^{\xi}}{\sqrt{\xi}}$.

We need to show that 
$f^{\prime}(t)=\frac{\frac{e^t}{\sqrt{t}}-\int_{0}^{t}\frac{e^{\xi}}{\sqrt{\xi}}}{e^{t}}<0$ for $t>1$.
The latter follows if we show that the function $g$ where

$$g(t):=\int_{0}^{t}\frac{e^{\xi}}{\sqrt{\xi}}-\frac{e^t}{\sqrt{t}}$$
is positive for $t>1$.

Now
$$g(1):=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{\xi}}{\sqrt{\xi}}-e$$
It turns out that $g(1)=\sqrt{\pi}\,\mathrm{erfi}(1)-e>2.9-e>0$
(Can we do the latter estimate analytically ?)

Finally,

$$g^{\prime}(t):=\frac{e^{t}}{\sqrt{t}}-\frac{e^t}{\sqrt{t}}+
\frac{e^t}{2t^{\frac{3}{2}}}>0$$ 
So, $g$ is increasing and positive at $t=1$.

Comment: "Can we do the latter estimate analytically" - yes, trivially so. Note $e^x > 1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2$ so that $\int_0^1 \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{x}} > \int_0^1 \frac{1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2}{\sqrt{x}} dx = \frac{43}{13} > \frac{11}{4} > e$ where the last inequality follows from the continued fraction for $e$, which can be derived without knowing the decimal expansion of $e$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us start without considering $t\geq 1.$

Set $F(t)=e^{-t}\int_{0}^t\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{x}} dx.$

Then 
$
F'(t)=-F(t)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ or equivalently $$F(t)=-F'(t)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}.$$

From the other side, $$F(t)\leq \int_0^{t}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}=2\sqrt{t}.$$

Putting together we get
 $$-F'(t)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\leq 2\sqrt{t}.$$ 
This leads to $$F'(t)\geq \frac{1-2t}{\sqrt{t}},$$
which is positive if $0\leq t \leq 1/2,$ but gives not an information for $t\geq 1.$

Comment: So this is only a partial answer?

Comment: oh, I unwillingly ignored the condition $t\geq 1.$ However, I let my approach posted for a while, it can inspire somebody (?)

Comment: I am not against not deleting wrong or incomplete answers. The opposite is true, I dislike compulsive erasers. However, just edit your answer, putting a line at the very beginning stating that this answer is incomplete, please. Otherwise people may get confused.

Comment: Edited, @Giuseppe.

Answer (score 0):

This is [Dawson function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_function)
$$F(t^2)=e^{-t^2}\int_{0}^{t^2}\frac{e^{x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx=2e^{-t^2}\int_0^te^{x^2}\ dx$$
let say $$g(t)=e^{-t^2}\int_0^te^{x^2}\ dx\implies g'(t)=1-2te^{-t}\int_0^te^{x^2}\ dx<0$$
because
$$2te^{-t}\int_0^te^{x^2}\ dx=e^{-t}\int_0^t2te^{x^2}\ dx>e^{-t}\int_0^t2xe^{x^2}\ dx>e^{-t}(e^{t^2}-1)>1$$
Wolfram shows this is true only for $t>\sim1.2$.

Comment: Brilliant idea to rescale. But incorrect calculus of the derivative ! please check. Thanks alot

Comment: Okay, you did not integrate by parts at some point, right? where did the integral $\int_{0}^{1} e^{xt}/\sqrt{x}dx$  go then?  You have a product of three functions in $t$ to differentiate. Please double check!

Comment: Thank you for your help, but still, there a mistake in the variable/measure change step. Look at the first and last quantities after "F(t)=" these can nor be equal except at $t=1$. Please check.

Comment: @Medo see edit. delete unrelated comments, please!

Comment: Thanks a lot. We could also finish the last problem analytically without Wolfram of course. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: The first derivative with respect to $t$ is given by
$$f'(t)-{{\rm e}^{-t}}\sqrt {\pi}{\it erfi} \left( \sqrt {t} \right) +{\frac 
{{{\rm e}^{-t}}{{\rm e}^{t}}}{\sqrt {t}}}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Not very helpful though since one still has the equally difficult task of verifying that $f^{\prime}<0$.